# Missing last word in a sentence when using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Code:

```
import re

def main():
    a=['the mississippi is well worth reading about', ' it is not a commonplace river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable']
    b=word_find(a)
    print(b)

def word_find(sentence_list):
    word_list=[]
    word_reg=re.compile(r"[\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;]?(.+?)[\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;]")
    for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
        words=re.findall(word_reg,sentence_list[i])
        word_list.append(words)
    return word_list

main()
```

What I need is to break every words into single elements of a list

now the output looks like this:

```
[['the', 'mississippi', 'is', 'well', 'worth', 'reading'], ['it', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways']]
```

I found that the last word of the first sentence `'about'` and the second sentence `'remarkable'`is missing

It might be some problem in my regular expression

```
word_reg=re.compile(r"[\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;]?(.+?)[\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;]")
```

But if I add a **question mark** into the last part of this regular expression like this:

```
[\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;]**?**")
```

the result become many single letters instead of words. What can I do with it?

---

**Edit:**

The reason why I didn't use *string.split* is that there might be many ways for people to break words

For example: when people input `a--b`, there is no space, but we have to break it into 'a','b'

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want to split the string on the whitespace like `string.split(' ')` ?

Comment: I edited the question to explain why not string.split(" ")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the *right* tools is always the winning strategy. In your case, the right tool is the NLTK word tokenizer, because it was designed to do just that: break sentences into words.

```
import nltk
a = ['the mississippi is well worth reading about', 
     ' it is not a commonplace river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable']
nltk.word_tokenize(a[1])
#['it', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', ',', 'but', 
# 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggest a simpler solution:

```
b = re.split(r"[\W_]", a)
```

The regex `[\W_]` matches any single non-word characters (non-letter and non-digit and non-underline) plus the underline, which is practically enough.

Your current regex requires that the word is followed by one of the characters in your list, but not "end of line", which can be matched with `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either find what you don't want and split on that:

```
>>> a=['the mississippi is well worth reading about', ' it is not a commonplace river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable']
>>> [re.split(r'\W+', s) for s in a]
[['the', 'mississippi', 'is', 'well', 'worth', 'reading', 'about'], ['', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']]
```

(You may need to filter the `''` elements produced by `re.split`)

Or capture what you do want with `re.findall` and keep those elements:

```
>>> [re.findall(r'\b\w+', s) for s in a]
[['the', 'mississippi', 'is', 'well', 'worth', 'reading', 'about'], ['it', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` and `filter`:

```
filter(None, re.split("[, \-!?:]+", a])
```

Where I have put the string `"[, \-!?:]+"`, you should put whatever characters it is that are your delimiters. `filter` will just remove any empty strings because of leading/trailing separators.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody

From others answers, the solution is to use re.split()

and there is a SUPER STAR **NLTK** in the uppermost answer

```
def word_find(sentence_list):
    word_list=[]
    for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
        word_list.append(re.split('\(|\)|,|\'|\"|:|\[|\]|\{|\}| |\-\-+|\t|;',sentence_list[i]))
    return word_list
```

Comment: No need to use that many `|` (or), try this instead [`[(),'":\[\]{} \t;-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/KWCMYr/1)